# Can't lookup an RMI server in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, bind, rmi

I can't lookup a object from a RMI servlet!

The error is: (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Server code:

```
public class CrecheServer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.rmi.RemoteException
     * @throws java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(7700);
        Metodo metodo = new Metodo();
        registry.bind("RMI", metodo);
        System.out.println("Servidor Ativo!");
    }

}
```

Servlet on client:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, RemoteException, NotBoundException, ParseException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 7700);
        Metodo metodo = (Metodo) reg.lookup("RMI");
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String sexo = request.getParameter("sexo");
        String dtNascimento = request.getParameter("dtNascimento");
        String cpf = request.getParameter("cpf");
        String telefone = request.getParameter("tel");
        String logradouro = request.getParameter("logradouro");
        String quadra = request.getParameter("quadra");
        metodo.CadastroResponsavel(nome, sexo, dtNascimento, cpf, telefone, logradouro, quadra);
        request.setAttribute("url", "sucesso");
        RequestDispatcher r = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        r.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

I have the interface and the class on client and server. This is the line, that doesn't work:

```
            Metodo metodo = (Metodo) reg.lookup("RMI");
```

Comment: That's not the error. That's only a parenthetical remark *about* the error. Post, and indeed *read,* the *actual* error message and the stack trace. Edit them into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it! The name of a package of class metodo, was diferent in the client